# Android/Java: showDialog with arguments?

Tags: java, android, arguments, showdialog

Javadoc says:

> void android.app.Activity.showDialog(int id)
>
> public final void showDialog (int id) 
>   Since: API Level 1  Simple version of
>   showDialog(int, Bundle) that does not
>   take any arguments. Simply calls
>   showDialog(int, Bundle) with null
>   arguments.

But if I try to use showDialog(int, Bundle), it says:

> The method showDialog(int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (int, Bundle)

So what am I doing wrong or which other possibillity is there for giving an argument to the Dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

showDialog(int, Bundle) was added in API level 8.  I would guess that you are using an earlier API level in your app.

Comment: @Lord Flash In case you didn't notice, in the API docs the API level for each method is indicated on the far right.